# Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'. in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to use form array for create a dynamic form .

i create a this form in ts file :

```
  createForm(): void {
    this.addQuestionForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        title: [
        '', Validators.compose(
            [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.maxLength(this.val.maxLen.title)
            ])
        ],
        courseExamId: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
        courseOptions: this._formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }

  // Initial FormArray
  createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
        optionTitle: [
        '', Validators.compose(
            [
            Validators.required
            ])
        ],
        isCorrect: [
        false,
        Validators.compose(
            [
            Validators.required]
        )
        ]
    });
  }
```

and this is mt code in html for using the form array :

```
  <div formArrayName="courseOptions" class="row m-auto"
                            *ngFor="let project of addQuestionForm.get('courseOptions').controls; let i = index">
                            <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                                <!-- optionTitle -->
                                <div class="col-lg-10 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile">
                                    <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field-fluid" appearance="outline">
                                        <mat-label>{{'COURSE_QUESTION.ANSWER' | translate}} *</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput formControlName="optionTitle"
                                            [placeholder]="'COURSE_QUESTION.ANSWER' | translate">
                                        <mat-error *ngIf="addQuestionForm.get('title').errors?.required">
                                            {{ 'COURSE_QUESTION.VALIDATIONS.REQUIRED.ANSWER' | translate }}
                                        </mat-error>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <!-- isCorrect -->
                                <div class="col-lg-1 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile icon">
                                    <mat-radio-group name="radp" aria-label="Select an option"
                                        formControlName="isCorrect">
                                        <mat-radio-button value='true'>{{'COURSE_QUESTION.TRUE' | translate}}
                                        </mat-radio-button>
                                    </mat-radio-group>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-1 kt-margin-bottom-20-mobile icon remove text-center">
                                    <label (click)="deleteItem(i)"><i class="la la-trash"></i></label>
                                </div>
                            </ng-container>
                        </div>
                        <div class="add-Item">
                            <button (click)="AddItems()" mat-raised-button type="button" color="accent"> <i
                                    class="la la-plus"></i>{{'COURSE_QUESTION.ADD_NEW_OPTION' |translate}}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

but when i need to use this page it show me this error :

> Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

**Whats the Problem? How can i Solve This ???**

Comment: courseOptions does not have any shape. You should assing the createItem() to courseOptions array

Comment: @Chellappan how can i assing  that ????

Comment: Assign createItem to course options array. courseOptions: this._formBuilder.array([this.createItem()])

Comment: @Chellappan still show error

Comment: check this example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fc-example

Comment: @Chellappan when i use it with`ng serve` it not have a problem and it worked . but when i need to `build` the project and `ng build --prod` it show me that error

Comment: Are you sure  about the above code causing build errors?

Comment: @Chellappan yes man . `ERROR in src/app/views/pages/post/components/post-edit/post-files/post-files.component.html(15,39): : Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.`

Comment: @Chellappan i sovle it . i must use the `controls` by this case `[controls]` in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is how you form the .html, must be like

```
<!--first a div with the name of the form Array-->
<div formArrayName="courseOptions">
  <!--after the loop-->
  <div class="row m-auto" 
       *ngFor="let project of addQuestionForm.get('courseOptions').controls; let i = index">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```

But I'm not sure, perhafs you need create a getter for you FormArray

```
get courseOptions()
{
    return this.addQuestionForm? this.addQuestionForm.get('courseOptions') as Form Array:null
}
```

And in your .html

```
<div formArrayName="courseOptions">
  <div class="row m-auto" *ngFor="let project of courseOptions.controls; let i = index">
  ...
  </div>
</div>
```